# Google map clear specific marker help (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase

I'm trying to use a combination of firebase and google maps API to create interactive markers on a map.

I can generate markers, but I want to find a way to remove them.

I generate a list of addresses that include a button you can pus. If pushed, the button removes the marker by setting setMap to null.

However, when referencing my markers in the clearItem function it give ems the error "cannot reference setMap of undefined"

Any help?

I use an array such as

var markerArray = [];

```
firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot)
{
    var pointerLocations = document.getElementById("locations");
    var databaseKeys = snapshot.val(); //Returns one object of many object attributes

    var list="";

    if(databaseKeys == null){
        console.log("Error handled");
    }

    else{

        for(i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(databaseKeys).length; i ++){
            list += databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].address + "<br>";
            list += databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].name + "<br>";
            var keyString = Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i].toString();
            list += "<button class = \"clrbtn\" id = \"clrbtn_"+i+"\" onclick = \"clearItem('"+keyString+"',"+i+")\">Delete Item</button>"
            //Calls google map

            codeAddress(databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].address, map,i);

        } 
    }
    pointerLocations.innerHTML = list;
}
);


function codeAddress(address,mapGlobl,i) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == 'OK') {
      //  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        markers.push(marker);



      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }


function clearItem(databaseID,position){
    firebase.database().ref(databaseID).remove();
    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

EDIT: Responding to comment

Using the i variable to use an object instead of array

```
firebase.database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot)
{
    var pointerLocations = document.getElementById("locations");
    var databaseKeys = snapshot.val(); //Returns one object of many object attributes

    var list="";

    if(databaseKeys == null){
        console.log("Error handled");
    }
    else{

        for(i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(databaseKeys).length; i ++){
            list += databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].address + "<br>";
            list += databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].name + "<br>";
            var keyString = Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i].toString();
            list += "<button class = \"clrbtn\" id = \"clrbtn_"+i+"\" onclick = \"clearItem('"+keyString+"',"+i+")\">Delete Item</button>"
            //Calls google map

            codeAddress(databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].address, databaseKeys[Object.keys(databaseKeys)[i]].name, map,i);

        } 
    }
    pointerLocations.innerHTML = list;
}
);

function codeAddress(address, name, mapGlobl,i) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == 'OK') {
      //  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        latLongObj[i] = {lat : results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng : results[0].geometry.location.lng(), add: address, name : name};

        console.log("Placing Market at " + i);
        markers['marker'+i] = marker;



      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }


function clearItem(databaseID,position){


    console.log(markers);

    console.log("Removing at position: "+ position);

    firebase.database().ref(databaseID).remove();

    markers['marker'+position].setMap(null);

    delete markers['marker'+position];

    console.log(markers);
}
```

Comment: On the line `markers[i].setMap(null);` inside the `clearItem()` function, where is `i` coming from? Is that supposed to be `markers[position].setMap(null);`?

Comment: That is an error, but it still gives the same error message when fixed

Comment: Where do you define the `markers` array initially? I see in your original question you said you used "var markerArray = [];" but I can't tell if that's part of the code block, and it has a different name. Make sure you're doing something like `var markers = [];` *outside* of a function so it's a global variable and works across multiple function calls.

Comment: It is declared globally

Comment: I noticed that you're passing `i` into the 3rd argument of `codeAddress()`, but you're not using it anywhere inside there. I think your array indexes are getting off. Instead of `markers.push(marker);`, try doing `markers[i] = marker;`

Comment: Thanks! But I was passing the i because I tried to modify using the index instead of push to see if it would help! I also tried a version with an object instead of array, but it leads to the same problem.. An example of that can be seen in the edited OP

Comment: So is there another error you're seeing? You can still use my suggestion with the array version in the OP. I was just suggesting that one line change.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(typeof markers[0]);`?

Comment: @CameronRoe it is undefined

Comment: @IanDrake I have tried it previously, and it didn't work. I think the issue is that markers is undefined

Comment: Is `markers` undefined or `markers[0]` undefined? This is a very important distinction.

Comment: When I do typeOf marker[0], it leads to undefined. When I do typeOf markers, it returns an object (since I am doing it using the object method, not an array)

Comment: Do you mean `typeof marker[0]` or `typeof markers[0]`. Those are two different variables.

Comment: markers, with an s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141748/discussion-between-cameron-roe-and-alexp2603).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `geocoder.geocode()` function is asynchronous. From the Google Maps JS documentation:

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous, since the Google Maps API needs to make a call to an external server. For that reason, you need to pass a callback method to execute upon completion of the request.

Your `markers.push(marker);` is happening inside that callback function. Since it's asynchronous, there's no guarantee when/if that will ever get called. The `push()` function will naively use the next available array index to add the marker to the array, but you're doing everything based on the `i` value you're passing around between function calls. If anything goes wrong with the Google Maps API and the callback function never gets called, or gets called after a delay (e.g. due to network latency), things may get added to the markers array out of order or with gaps in the array indices.

The simplest solution is to change `markers.push(marker);` to `markers[i] = marker;` This guarantees that it gets added to the markers array with the index you're expecting (and it matches up with the `i` value of that `<button>` element).